# Construct an example of sequence of RV

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Construct a sequence of random variables $X_n$, with below conditions:

1. $X_n \to -1  (Constant RV)$ in probability convergence, as $n\to\infty$.
2. $P(X_n\le -1)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$. (Which is the most confusing part, since convergence type is not indicated. What does that mean?)
3. E[$X_n$] diverging to  $\infty$ as  $n\to\infty$.

Let me explain what I think. First condition is pretty straightforward, at least using the definition. Then as I mentioned, I have not an idea about second condition since I did not understand. I can construct that $F_{x_n}(-1)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, then use it for convergence in distribution. However, in overall, I am very confused.

Comment: If condition 2 holds, then for $\epsilon < 1$ we have $P(|X_n-1| > \epsilon) \ge P(X_n \le -1) \to 1$ which contradicts condition 1. Is there a typo?

Comment: $P(X_n \le -1)$ is a sequence of real numbers… so there should be no confusion at all.

Comment: Condition 1 and 2 cannot be met at the same time. If we alter condition 1 to $|X_n|\rightarrow1$, we get something reasonable. The just take $n$ with $1/\sqrt n$ and $-1$ otherwise.

Comment: Let $X_n$ be given by $P(X_n=n)=1/\sqrt n$ and $P(X_n=-1)=1-1/\sqrt n$. Then the sequence converges to $-1$ in prob, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n\le -1)=1$ and the expectation diverges.

Comment: Good luck with the studies!

Comment: @Matija Hi, I've been sick for couple of days and finally constructed a solution. If you are still around, can you check my solution? (I will edit the question with my answer based on your reply :) )

Comment: Sure! I'm still around and interested!

Comment: @Matija Edited!

Comment: In this example we have $X_n\rightarrow -1$. As suggested above, Item 1 and Item 2 cannot both hold.

Comment: @Matija Just talked about whether there is a typo. Item1 is changed now. Sorry about confusion, but not caused by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ let $X_n\in\mathbb R$ be given by $\mathbb P(X_n=-1)=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\mathbb P(X_n=n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

1. We use the definition for convergence in probability from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability). So, let $\varepsilon>0$ and notice that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(|X_n-(-1)|>\varepsilon)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(X_n=n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$. This shows that $X_n$ converges to $-1$ in probability, where as usual $-1$ is a constant random variable in this context.
2. We have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(X_n\le-1)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})=1$. This is just the standard limit, i.e. for the sequence $a_n=\mathbb P(X_n\le-1)$ of real numbers we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=1$.
3. We have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb E[X_n]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}((1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})\cdot(-1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\sqrt n)=\infty$.

When confronted with all of the different types of convergence for random variables and distributions, it is hard to properly interpret $\alpha_n\rightarrow\alpha$. The way I solve this problem is that first of all, I check what $\alpha_n$ is. For example, if $\alpha_n$ is a number in $\mathbb R$, like for example $\alpha_n=\mathbb P(X_n\le -1)\in[0,1]$, then I know it's the standard limit. If $\alpha_n:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is a random variable, like $\alpha_n=X_n$ in this example, then I expect that the mode of convergence is mentioned somewhere in the text. The same is true if $\alpha_n$ is a probability distribution. To make things even worse, $\alpha_n:\mathcal D\rightarrow\mathbb R$ could also be functions, in which case $\alpha_n\rightarrow\alpha$ usually means pointwise convergence. Truth is, this notation is very overloaded, and should be dealt with carefully.

Comment: I agree. I've constructed most of the thing you proved here, however they were disorganized and I was not sure whether they are true. Thank you so much! Also, I believe that the question is not crystal clear, however this is a good question since most of the convergence proofs are straight-forward and does not require any creative thinking imo.